# CSV Reader not getting the right value from array

Tags: python, oop, csv

Below is a class I am making to calculate checkbook transactions. My issue lies in the `elif` statements where I check if `row[0] == "starting"` or `"ending"`. In the csv file which I will also copy and paste, it clearly states in `row[0]` that those words are there, but my `startAmt` and `endAmt` both continue equalling `0` when running.

```
class Checkbook:
"""Checkbook class for list of check transactions"""

def __init__(self, filename):
    """initializer for Checkbook class"""

    self.name = filename
    self.debitList = []
    self.creditList = []
    self.startAmt = 0
    self.endAmt = 0.0

    with open(filename) as csvFile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter = ',')

        for row in readCSV:

            try: 
                if (row[2] == " debit"):

                    debitAmt = row[3]
                    self.debitList.append(debitAmt)

                elif (row[2] == " credit"):

                    creditAmt = row[3]
                    self.creditList.append(creditAmt)

                elif (row[0] == "starting"):
                    self.startAmt += row[1]

                elif (row[0] == "ending"):
                    self.endAmt += row[1]

            except IndexError:
                pass
```

and this is the .csv file:

```
starting, 1000
3/1/16, Valvoline, debit, 70.00
3/1/16, Panera Bread, debit, 12.59
3/4/16, ShopRite Groceries, debit, 100.69
3/5/16, Paycheck, credit, 248.39
3/10/16, Whole Paycheck Groceries, debit, 103.23
3/12/16, Fancy Restaurant, debit, 150.34
3/18/16, Burger King, debit, 8.34
3/19/16, Paycheck, credit, 248.39
3/23/16, ATM Withdrawal, debit, 40.0,
3/24/16, Whole Paycheck Groceries, debit, 248.39
3/28/16, Fancy Restaurant, debit, 112.34
ending, 651.36
```

If anyone knows why it is not registering those strings as being there then please let me know!

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to an  `int` first:

```
self.startAmt += int(row[1])
```

Comment: I tried that but I think the issue is that the if statement isn't picking up the fact that "starting" is in row[0]. I tried replacing self.startAmt += int(row[1]) with print("something") and nothing printed.

Comment: Then please edit your question and include only the minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that all values read from the file are strings and not numbers. If you want to do calculations, you'll have to convert the values intelligently.

You can also simplify your logic a bit; at the same time improve your code by limiting what is in the try/except block. A large statement body in the try block causes problems when trying to debug an issue.

So, lets start with the fact that the reader will always give you a list. If the list has two elements, you know its the starting/ending balance row. Otherwise, its a row that is showing the complete transaction details.

```
with open(filename) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(filename, delimiter=',') # , is the default, so you
                                                 # can eliminate this
    for row in reader:
       if len(row) == 2:
          balance_type, value = row
          if balance_type == 'starting':
             self.start_amt += float(value)
          if balance_type == 'ending':
             self.end_amt += float(value)
       else:
          if len(row) == 4:
              trans_date, comment, trans_type, amount = row
              if trans_type == 'debit':
                  self.debit_list.append(float(amount))
              if trans_type == 'credit':
                  self.credit_list.append(float(amount))
          else:
             # We have some garbage data
             print('Invalid data {}'.format(row))
```

Now we are doing some explicit checks to avoid errors when parsing our information.

This may look like some redundant code but whenever you are dealing with external data (like a file, user input, information from a database or network resource) it is always good to assume that you will be getting junk data and be as explicit and through in checking/validating that data.

Answer (score 0):

class file:
`import csv
class Checkbook(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.name =filename
        self.debitList = []
        self.creditList = []
        self.startAmt = 0
        self.endAmt = 0.0
    def Parse(self):
        with open(self.name) as csvFile:
            readCSV = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter = ',')
            for row in readCSV:
                if (len(row) > 2):
                    if (row[2] == " debit"):
                        debitAmt = row[3]
                        self.debitList.append(debitAmt)
                            #print "debitlist"self.debitList
                    elif (row[2] == " credit"):
                        creditAmt = row[3]
                        self.creditList.append(creditAmt)
                else:
                    if (row[0] == "starting"):
                        self.startAmt += int(row[1])
                    elif(row[0] == "ending"):
                        self.endAmt += float(row[1])
        return self.debitList,self.creditList,self.startAmt,self.endAmt`class file:

driver file:

`import csvread
obj=csvread.Checkbook("text.csv")
db,cl,sa,ea=obj.Parse()
print db,cl,sa,ea`

Comment: Above part is our python module by loading that module we have accessed vaule which we need.
your start and ending variables declaed with 0 if you want increment one then make change those values as 1